# Bayesian model (Gibbs sampling) with frequency data for non-standard distribution

Tags: bayesian, gibbs, frequency, jags

I have the following model.
\begin{align}
X &= D\,(F+S\,(1+G)) \\
D &\sim \mathrm{Exp}\,(\lambda) \\
F &\sim \mathrm{Unif}\,(0,1) \\
S &\sim \mathrm{Poi}\,(\sigma) \\
G &\sim \mathrm{Unif}\,(0,2) \\
\end{align}
which I want to fit via Gibbs sampling - i.e., estimate $\lambda, \sigma$, both with uninformative priors. The problem is: the available data are not realizations of $X$, but rather frequency (proportion) data for some (~5) ranges of $X$, which also have confidence intervals - e.g., $P(0 \le X < 2) = 0.22$, 95% CI: $(0.19,0.26)$.

If $X$ had a standard distribution, we could use the cumulative distribution function to model $P(0 \le X < 2)$, but the construction of $X$ as shown from other random variables leaves me lost as to how to use the available frequency data, much less the confidence intervals for these proportions.

Things I've tried (repeated for all given strata $k$):

1. I modelled $\phi_k = P(X\in\mathbf{X}_k) \sim \mathrm{Beta}\,(N_k \rho_k, N_k(1-\rho_k))$ - i.e., beta approximation of binomial distribution, fixing $\rho_k$ as the point estimate ($0.22$) and fitting $N_k$ to reproduce the 95% CI as best as possible. This at least incorporates the 95% CI if the proportion is interpreted as a random variable.
2. I empirically sampled $N \approx 300$ (representative of the data) values of $X$ *each iteration* and defined an empiric estimate $\hat{\rho}_k = \mathrm{mean}\,\{1 \mathrm{~if~} X\in\mathbf{X}_k; 0 \mathrm{~else}\}$. Then, I used $\hat{\rho}_k$ in place of the observed $\rho_k$ to define a likelihood of the observed $\rho_k$ under the empiric mean and $N_k$. But this feels wrong as the variance is inflated, and the posteriors of $F$ and $G$ are no different than the priors, suggesting the model is not converging (I think?).

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of confidence intervals on the (aggregated) data, because this appears like a deterministic constraint on the model parameters.

Comment: These proportion data are RDS-adjusted (respondent driven sampling), which gives the confidence intervals - but yes they should be also subject to $\sum_k\rho_k =1$